# How many concurrent connections can windows 2008 r2 make to a UNC fileshare?

Tags: windows-server-2008, server-message-block, unc

We have an application that makes request to a UNC path for files and serves them via IIS.

How many concurrent connections can a process on Windows 2008 r2 make to a UNC file share?

Are there any specific limitations on this, or is it purely a based on physical resource constraints (and number of available ports for TCP/IP connections).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your UNC file share is also a Windows server, then the max is really only limited by CAL licenses owned (but not actually set anywhere but on paper).

Since this is asking concurrent connections, you can check it here (on the server with the share):

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Shares

Look at the share and there is a REG_MULTI_SZ that should say "MaxUses"

the default is some crazy high number like 4294967295 (65536 times 65536 minus 1) based on ports like you say (no it's not a reference to Excel :) )

Comment: Thanks, this is useful, though I need to check with our ops guys to see if the share is Windows or a Linux share masquerading as a windows share. :-)